# Is hsearch_r thread-safe?

Tags: c, glibc

Can I use `hcreate_r`, `hsearch_r` and `hdestroy_r` in a thread-safe manner?

Do I have to wrap all calls to it with a mutex lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the manpage of `HSEARCH(3)`:

> The `hcreate_r()`, `hsearch_r()`, and `hdestroy_r()` functions are thread-safe.

So no, you do not need to wrap the calls with any sort of locking.

In general, functions suffixed with `_r` tend to be *re-entrant* versions of the same function without the `_r` suffix (such as `strtok_r`). Their re-entrant nature (usually) makes them intrinsically thread-safe.

Comment: Huh, the manpage installed on my Debian system doesn't include that sentence. Looks like the updated package does.

Comment: For me, it's in the **ATTRIBUTES** section (just before **CONFORMING TO**)

Comment: It's in Ubuntu's manpages-dev package version 3.54-1ubuntu1, but not in Debian's version 3.44-1.